# Are there any good / interesting analogs to regular expressions in 2d?

Tags: regex, algorithm, language-agnostic, graphics

Are there any good (or at least interesting but flawed) analogs to regular expressions in two dimensions?

In one dimension I can write something like `/aaac?(bc)*b?aaa/` to quickly pull out a region of alternating `b`s and `c`s with a border of at least three `a`s.  Perhaps as importantly, I can come back a month later and see at a glance what it's looking for.

I'm finding myself writing custom code for analogous problems in 2d (some much more complicated / constrained) and it would be nice to have a more concise and standardized notation, even if I have to write the engine behind it myself.

A second example might be called "find the +".  The goal is to locate a column of 3 or more `a`s, a `b` bracketed by 3 or more `a`s with three or more `a`s below.  It should match:

```
..7...hkj.k f
7...a  h o j 
----a--------
 j .a,g- 8 9 
.aaabaaaaa7 j
 k .a,,g- h j
 hh a----?  j
    a   hjg
```

and might be written as [b^(a{3})v(a{3})>(a{3})<(a{3})] or...

Suggestions?

Comment: regular expressions end up being state machines, doing such a state machine on a 2d space sounds exceptionaly complex (and a general solution without considerable cleverness would be very slow. Just detecting connected regions is quite complex which this would rely on...

Comment: I would suggest building a library to enumerate regions (where many implementations exist, for example manifolds, internal patterns) and then make regions have several useful well defined operations on them, like traversing the borders and at each point checking the values around it etc.

Comment: I should have made this an answer :)
Then use the objects/structures returned from these functions in a chained fashion (lambdas or anon classes will make this much easier) to make the code read more easily e.g.:
bitmap.FindWithPattern('bc').Where(r => r.Border.All(p => p.Exterior[3] == 'aaa'))

Comment: @ShuggyCoUk It's not too late to make it an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not being a regex expert, but finding the problem interesting, I looked around and found this interesting [blog entry](http://timepedia.blogspot.com/2007/09/knowledge-extraction-with-2-dimensional.html). Especially the syntax used there for defining the 2D regex looks appealing. The paper linked there might tell you more than me.

**Update from comment:** Here is the link to the primary author's page where you can download the linked paper *"Two-dimensional languages"*: http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~giammarr/Research/pubbl.html

Comment: Now why didn't google turn that up for me?  Oh well, no worries.  This sounds like exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: After browsing through the paper I'm declaring this the solution.  If anyone is interested, the paper behind the blog entry is linked from the primary author's page here http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~giammarr/Research/pubbl.html without needing to pay a publisher for the privilege of downloading it.

Answer (score 4):

Nice problem.

First, ask yourself if you can constrain the pattern to a "+" pattern, or if you would it need to test/match rectangles also.  For instance, a *rectangle* of `[bc]` with `a` border of `a` would match the center rectangle below, but would also match a "+" shape of  `[c([bc]*a})v([bc]*a)>([bc]*a)<([bc]*a)]` (in your syntax)

```
xxxaaaaaxxx
yzyabcba12d
defabcbass3
oreabcba3s3
s33aaaaas33
k388x.egiee
```

If you can constrain it to a "+" then your task is much easier.  As ShuggyCoUk said, parsing a RE is usually equivalent to a DFSM -- but for a single, serial input which simplifies things greatly.

In your "RE+" engine, you'll have to debug not only the engine, but also each place that the expressions are entered.  I'd like the compiler to catch any errors it could.  Given that, you could also use something that was explicitly four RE's, like:

```
REPlus engine = new REPlus('b').North("a{3}")
   .East("a{3}").South("a{3}").West("a{3}");
```

However, depending on your implementation this may be cumbersome.

And with regard to the traversal engine -- would the North/West patterns match RtL or LtR?  It could matter if the patterns match differently with or w/o greedy sub-matches.

*Incidentally, I think the '^' in your example is supposed to be one character to the left, outside the parenthesis.*

Comment: Fixed the `^` typo, thanks.  The "+" example is just one--the border and pattern fill is another.  Also I've got something that finds closed circuits with restricted path widths, various "bracketing" structures, and probably a few others (once you recognize a tool you often find unexpected uses).

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions are designed to model patterns in one dimension.  As I understand it, you want to match patterns in a two dimensional array of characters.

Can you use regular expressions?  That depends on whether the property that you are searching for is decomposable into components which can be matched in one dimension or not.  If so, you can run your regular expressions on columns and rows, and look for intersections in the solution sets from those.  Depending on the particular problem you have, this may either solve the problem, or it may find areas in your 2d array which are likely to be solutions.

Whether your problem is decomposable or not, I think writing some custom code will be inevitable.  But at least it sounds like an interesting problem, so the work should be pleasant.

Answer (score 3):

You're essentially talking about a [spatial query language](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=512161.512186).  There are plenty out there if you look up spatial query, geographic query and graphic querying.  The spatial part generally comes down to points, lines and objects in a region that have other given attributes.  Regions can be specified as polygons, distance from a point (e.g. circles), distance from a linear feature such as a road, all points on one side of a linear feature, etc...  You can then get into more complex queries like set of all nearest neighbours, shortest path, travelling salesman, and tesselations like Delaunay TINs and Voronoi diagrams.

Comment: While interesting, that doesn't seem to be quite what I'm looking for.  What I've found seems to be about geometric properties in a continuum, while I'm more interested in structural features on a lattice.